# Failed to install flatpak on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: flatpak, gnome-builder

I was trying to install gnome builder as instructed in this article https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Builder 
but the flatpak installation failed with following error:

```
Failed to install org.gnome.Sdk/x86_64/3.30: While pulling runtime/org.gnome.Sdk/x86_64/3.30 from remote flathub: Peer failed to perform TLS handshake
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved once I connected my router cable directly to the pc, without the Wifi. Still i believe some bug may be present with the flatpak  download manager.